# SQL Alias to Dynamic Query

Tags: 7, views, database

I have a complex views SQL query, that I have converted to a dynamic query which works perfectly -- my issue is with custom fields:

```
'node' AS field_data_field_description_node_entity_type,
'node' AS field_data_field_menu_photo_node_entity_type,
'node' AS field_data_field_price_node_entity_type
```

**How do I replicate these, this is the only part I am baffled by...** I am doing all of this using `hook_views_pre_execute()`, here is the original SQL returned by views (providing it so you can see the complexity):

```
SELECT node.nid AS nid,node.title AS node_title,
taxonomy_term_data_node.name AS taxonomy_term_data_node_name,
taxonomy_term_data_node.vid AS taxonomy_term_data_node_vid,
taxonomy_term_data_node.tid AS taxonomy_term_data_node_tid,
taxonomy_term_data_node.weight AS taxonomy_term_data_node_weight,
taxonomy_term_data_node__taxonomy_vocabulary.machine_name AS taxonomy_term_data_node__taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name,
taxonomy_term_data_taxonomy_term_hierarchy.name AS taxonomy_term_data_taxonomy_term_hierarchy_name,
taxonomy_term_data_taxonomy_term_hierarchy.vid AS taxonomy_term_data_taxonomy_term_hierarchy_vid,
taxonomy_term_data_taxonomy_term_hierarchy.tid AS taxonomy_term_data_taxonomy_term_hierarchy_tid,
taxonomy_term_data_taxonomy_term_hierarchy.weight AS taxonomy_term_data_taxonomy_term_hierarchy_weight,
taxonomy_term_data_taxonomy_term_hierarchy__taxonomy_vocabulary.machine_name AS taxonomy_term_data_taxonomy_term_hierarchy__taxonomy_vocabul,
taxonomy_index.weight AS taxonomy_index_weight,
'node' AS field_data_field_description_node_entity_type,
'node' AS field_data_field_menu_photo_node_entity_type,
'node' AS field_data_field_price_node_entity_type
FROM {node} node
INNER JOIN (SELECT td.*, tn.nid AS nid FROM {taxonomy_term_data} td
INNER JOIN {taxonomy_vocabulary} tv ON td.vid = tv.vid
INNER JOIN {taxonomy_index} tn ON tn.tid = td.tid
WHERE (tv.machine_name IN  ('*DYNAMIC_VOCAB_MACHINE_NAME*')) ) taxonomy_term_data_node ON node.nid = taxonomy_term_data_node.nid
LEFT JOIN {taxonomy_term_hierarchy} taxonomy_term_data_node__taxonomy_term_hierarchy ON taxonomy_term_data_node.tid = taxonomy_term_data_node__taxonomy_term_hierarchy.tid
LEFT JOIN {taxonomy_term_data} taxonomy_term_data_taxonomy_term_hierarchy ON taxonomy_term_data_node__taxonomy_term_hierarchy.parent = taxonomy_term_data_taxonomy_term_hierarchy.tid
LEFT JOIN {users} users_node ON node.uid = users_node.uid
LEFT JOIN {taxonomy_vocabulary} taxonomy_term_data_node__taxonomy_vocabulary ON taxonomy_term_data_node.vid = taxonomy_term_data_node__taxonomy_vocabulary.vid
LEFT JOIN {taxonomy_vocabulary} taxonomy_term_data_taxonomy_term_hierarchy__taxonomy_vocabulary ON taxonomy_term_data_taxonomy_term_hierarchy.vid = taxonomy_term_data_taxonomy_term_hierarchy__taxonomy_vocabulary.vid
LEFT JOIN {taxonomy_index} taxonomy_index ON node.nid = taxonomy_index.nid
WHERE (( (users_node.uid = '*DYNAMIC_USER_ID*' ) )AND(( (node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN  ('*NODE_TYPE*')) )))
```

Here is the dynamic query, an exact replica of the above minus the `'node' AS` black magic:

```
// dynamically add vocabulary machine name
$query_vocab = db_select('taxonomy_term_data', 'td');
$query_vocab->innerJoin('taxonomy_vocabulary', 'tv', 'td.vid = tv.vid');
$query_vocab->innerJoin('taxonomy_index', 'tn', 'tn.tid = td.tid');
$query_vocab->condition('tv.machine_name', array($vocab_machine_name));
$query_vocab->fields('td')->addField('tn', 'nid', 'nid');

// main query
$query = db_select('node', 'node');

// joins
$query->innerJoin($query_vocab, 'taxonomy_term_data_node', 'node.nid = taxonomy_term_data_node.nid');
$query->leftJoin('taxonomy_term_hierarchy', 'taxonomy_term_data_node__taxonomy_term_hierarchy', 'taxonomy_term_data_node.tid = taxonomy_term_data_node__taxonomy_term_hierarchy.tid');
$query->leftJoin('taxonomy_term_data', 'taxonomy_term_data_taxonomy_term_hierarchy', 'taxonomy_term_data_node__taxonomy_term_hierarchy.parent = taxonomy_term_data_taxonomy_term_hierarchy.tid');
$query->leftJoin('users', 'users_node', 'node.uid = users_node.uid');
$query->leftJoin('taxonomy_vocabulary', 'taxonomy_term_data_node__taxonomy_vocabulary', 'taxonomy_term_data_node.vid = taxonomy_term_data_node__taxonomy_vocabulary.vid');
$query->leftJoin('taxonomy_vocabulary', 'taxonomy_term_data_taxonomy_term_hierarchy__taxonomy_vocabulary', 'taxonomy_term_data_taxonomy_term_hierarchy.vid = taxonomy_term_data_taxonomy_term_hierarchy__taxonomy_vocabulary.vid');
$query->leftJoin('taxonomy_index', 'taxonomy_index', 'node.nid = taxonomy_index.nid');


// conditions
$query
  ->condition('node.status', 1)
  ->condition('node.type', array($node_type))
  ->condition('users_node.uid', $owner->uid);

// fields
$query->addField('node', 'nid', 'nid');
$query->addField('node', 'title', 'node_title');
$query->addField('taxonomy_term_data_node', 'name', 'taxonomy_term_data_node_name');
$query->addField('taxonomy_term_data_node', 'vid', 'taxonomy_term_data_node_vid');
$query->addField('taxonomy_term_data_node', 'tid', 'taxonomy_term_data_node_tid');
$query->addField('taxonomy_term_data_node', 'weight', 'taxonomy_term_data_node_weight');
$query->addField('taxonomy_term_data_node__taxonomy_vocabulary', 'machine_name', 'taxonomy_term_data_node__taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name');
$query->addField('taxonomy_term_data_taxonomy_term_hierarchy', 'name', 'taxonomy_term_data_taxonomy_term_hierarchy_name');
$query->addField('taxonomy_term_data_taxonomy_term_hierarchy', 'vid', 'taxonomy_term_data_taxonomy_term_hierarchy_vid');
$query->addField('taxonomy_term_data_taxonomy_term_hierarchy', 'tid', 'taxonomy_term_data_taxonomy_term_hierarchy_tid');
$query->addField('taxonomy_term_data_taxonomy_term_hierarchy', 'weight', 'taxonomy_term_data_taxonomy_term_hierarchy_weight');
$query->addField('taxonomy_term_data_taxonomy_term_hierarchy__taxonomy_vocabulary', 'machine_name', 'taxonomy_term_data_taxonomy_term_hierarchy__taxonomy_vocabul');
$query->addField('taxonomy_index', 'weight', 'taxonomy_index_weight');
```

If I add a `join` like `join('field_data_field_desciption', 'field_desc', 'field_desc.entity_id = node.nid')` I get no results. I might just opt for using `field_get_items()` in a `preprocess` function... but would rather not.

**Any guidance/help would be highly appreciated :)**

Comment: It should just be another join against a Field table ... kind of like you've mentioned as failing to achieve. I think you just need some more trial and error ...

Comment: These three columns have the static value 'node' in every row of the view. Give it a try on the command line: SELECT 'node' AS field_data_field_description_node_entity_type; ... they aren't used anywhere else in the query, so maybe you don't need them? I'd guess views uses it for rendering/theming. If you do need them, you can add them with $query->addExpression('node', 'field_data_field_description_node_entity_type'), etc. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3AaddExpression/7

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because this site is for questions, not challenges etc.

Comment: @Molot, did you even read the post, or compulsively commented? The word 'challenge' was just used to entice people ;)

Comment: @celabtr... interesting. Yes, I think it is used for rendering/theming, and I have thought about just leaving them out but I'd like for it to be complete as I am now missing these fields from my view (though can get them with `field_get_items`. When adding addExpression to the query, I again get no results. I'll have to read it a bit more... thanks for the tip!

Comment: and have you used devel / dpq on this query to confirm that the sql is the same?

Comment: @calebtr, thanks! i finally got around to this, and you are correct -- i need to use addExpression. This is a SQL alias, and after some trial/error/searching the expression needs to be before the conditions and addFields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out the following are SQL Aliases, this is related to the FieldAPI:

```
'node' AS field_data_field_description_node_entity_type,
'node' AS field_data_field_menu_photo_node_entity_type,
'node' AS field_data_field_price_node_entity_type
```

They are replicated using `addExpression` they **must be before any `conditions` and `addField`**. Adding the following to my code above replicates the SQL perfectly:

```
$query->addExpression("'node'", 'field_data_field_FIELD_NAME_node_entity_type');
```

Thanks to @calebtr for the help!